# traefik: hangs after msg="Server configuration reloaded on :80"

Tags: amazon-ec2, docker-machine, traefik

I am attempting to deploy a traefik app via docker-machine to an EC2 instance using the following commands:

```
docker-machine scp include/traefik.toml swarm-master:/home/ubuntu/traefik.toml
docker-machine scp include/acme.json swarm-master:/home/ubuntu/acme.json

docker $(docker-machine config swarm-master) run \
    -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
    -v $PWD/traefik.toml:/traefik.toml \
    -v $PWD/acme.json:/acme.json \
    -p 80:80 \
    -p 443:443 \
    -l traefik.frontend.rule=Host:traefik.domain.com \
    -l traefik.port=8080 \
    --network swarm-net \
    --name traefik \
    traefik:1.4.3-alpine \
    -l DEBUG \
    --docker
```

However, my application hangs after the following output:

```
 traefik.toml                                                                                                                                                                       100%  503    29.4KB/s   00:00    
 acme.json                                                                                                                                                                          100%    0     0.0KB/s   00:00    
 time="2017-11-21T21:39:44Z" level=info msg="Traefik version v1.4.3 built on 2017-11-14_11:14:24AM" 
 time="2017-11-21T21:39:44Z" level=debug msg="Global configuration loaded {"GraceTimeOut":10000000000,"Debug":false,"CheckNewVersion":true,"AccessLogsFile":"","AccessLog":null,"TraefikLogsFile":"","LogLevel":"DEBUG","EntryPoints":{"http":{"Network":"","Address":":80","TLS":null,"Redirect":null,"Auth":null,"WhitelistSourceRange":null,"Compress":false,"ProxyProtocol":null,"ForwardedHeaders":{"Insecure":true,"TrustedIPs":null}}},"Cluster":null,"Constraints":[],"ACME":null,"DefaultEntryPoints":["http"],"ProvidersThrottleDuration":2000000000,"MaxIdleConnsPerHost":200,"IdleTimeout":0,"InsecureSkipVerify":false,"RootCAs":null,"Retry":null,"HealthCheck":{"Interval":30000000000},"RespondingTimeouts":null,"ForwardingTimeouts":null,"Docker":{"Watch":true,"Filename":"","Constraints":null,"Trace":false,"DebugLogGeneratedTemplate":false,"Endpoint":"unix:///var/run/docker.sock","Domain":"","TLS":null,"ExposedByDefault":true,"UseBindPortIP":false,"SwarmMode":false},"File":null,"Web":null,"Marathon":null,"Consul":null,"ConsulCatalog":null,"Etcd":null,"Zookeeper":null,"Boltdb":null,"Kubernetes":null,"Mesos":null,"Eureka":null,"ECS":null,"Rancher":null,"DynamoDB":null}" 
 time="2017-11-21T21:39:44Z" level=info msg="Preparing server http &{Network: Address::80 TLS:<nil> Redirect:<nil> Auth:<nil> WhitelistSourceRange:[] Compress:false ProxyProtocol:<nil> ForwardedHeaders:0xc42008bae0} with readTimeout=0s writeTimeout=0s idleTimeout=3m0s" 
 time="2017-11-21T21:39:44Z" level=info msg="Starting provider *docker.Provider {"Watch":true,"Filename":"","Constraints":null,"Trace":false,"DebugLogGeneratedTemplate":false,"Endpoint":"unix:///var/run/docker.sock","Domain":"","TLS":null,"ExposedByDefault":true,"UseBindPortIP":false,"SwarmMode":false}" 
 time="2017-11-21T21:39:44Z" level=info msg="Starting server on :80" 
 time="2017-11-21T21:39:44Z" level=debug msg="Provider connection established with docker 17.05.0-ce (API 1.29)" 
 time="2017-11-21T21:39:44Z" level=debug msg="Filtering container with empty frontend rule /swarm-agent" 
 time="2017-11-21T21:39:44Z" level=debug msg="Filtering container with empty frontend rule /swarm-agent-master" 
 time="2017-11-21T21:39:44Z" level=debug msg="Validation of load balancer method for backend backend-traefik failed: invalid load-balancing method ''. Using default method wrr." 
 time="2017-11-21T21:39:44Z" level=debug msg="Configuration received from provider docker: {"backends":{"backend-traefik":{"servers":{"server-traefik":{"url":"http://172.31.48.2:8080","weight":0}},"loadBalancer":{"method":"wrr"}}},"frontends":{"frontend-Host-traefik-domain-com-0":{"entryPoints":["http"],"backend":"backend-traefik","routes":{"route-frontend-Host-traefik-domain-com-0":{"rule":"Host:traefik.domain.com"}},"passHostHeader":true,"priority":0,"basicAuth":[],"headers":{}}}}" 
 time="2017-11-21T21:39:44Z" level=debug msg="Last docker config received more than 2s, OK" 
 time="2017-11-21T21:39:44Z" level=debug msg="Creating frontend frontend-Host-traefik-domain-com-0" 
 time="2017-11-21T21:39:44Z" level=debug msg="Wiring frontend frontend-Host-traefik-domain-com-0 to entryPoint http" 
 time="2017-11-21T21:39:44Z" level=debug msg="Creating route route-frontend-Host-traefik-domain-com-0 Host:traefik.domain.com" 
 time="2017-11-21T21:39:44Z" level=debug msg="Creating backend backend-traefik" 
 time="2017-11-21T21:39:44Z" level=debug msg="Creating load-balancer wrr" 
 time="2017-11-21T21:39:44Z" level=debug msg="Creating server server-traefik at http://172.31.48.2:8080 with weight 0" 
 time="2017-11-21T21:39:44Z" level=info msg="Server configuration reloaded on :80" 
 ^Ctime="2017-11-21T21:39:59Z" level=info msg="I have to go... interrupt" 
 time="2017-11-21T21:39:59Z" level=info msg="Stopping server" 
 time="2017-11-21T21:39:59Z" level=debug msg="Waiting 10s seconds before killing connections on entrypoint http..." 
 time="2017-11-21T21:39:59Z" level=debug msg="Entrypoint http closed" 
 time="2017-11-21T21:39:59Z" level=info msg="Server stopped" 
 time="2017-11-21T21:39:59Z" level=info msg="Shutting down" 
 time="2017-11-21T21:39:59Z" level=error msg="Error creating server: http: Server closed"
```

**traefik.toml**:

```
 debug = false
 checkNewVersion = true
 logLevel = "DEBUG"
 defaultEntryPoints = ["http", "https"]

 [web]
 address = ":8080"
   [web.auth.basic]
   users = ["admin:alkdsjfalkdjflakdsjfalkdjfalkdjfaldkjf"]

 [entryPoints]
   [entryPoints.http]
   address = ":80"
     [entryPoints.http.redirect]
     entryPoint = "https"
   [entryPoints.https]
   address = ":443"
   [entryPoints.https.tls]

 [acme]
 email = "name@domain.com"
 storage = "acme.json"
 entryPoint = "https"
 onHostRule = true
 onDemand = false
```

and **acme.json** has permissions 600.

However, when I run the following (seemingly same) command after logging into my EC2 instance, traefik is successfully deployed:

```
 docker run \
    -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
    -v $PWD/traefik.toml:/traefik.toml \
    -v $PWD/acme.json:/acme.json \
    -p 80:80 \
    -p 443:443 \
    -l traefik.frontend.rule=Host:traefik.domain.com \
    -l traefik.port=8080 \
    --network swarm-net \
    --name traefik \
    traefik:1.4.3-alpine \
    -l DEBUG \
    --docker
```

Any reason why I am not deploying with docker-machine are greatly appreciated.  Thanks!